# Small particles in plastics can leak into the oil, which further reduces its quality

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, relative-clauses

'Plastic containers usually do not provide adequate protection from light, heat, or moisture;
additionally, small particles in plastics can leak into the oil, which further reduces its quality.'

What is the subject of the clause 'which further reduces its quality'? Is it whole clause of 'small particles can leak into the oil'?

Thank you for the help

Comment: The "subject" of the "which" clause is aforementioned ***the fact that** [plastic leaches into the oil]*.

Comment: Without a previous sentence focusing on oil, the natural referent of “its” in this the plastic container.